# Need Guidance on How to make Function Async/Non Blocking

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, dispatcher

Suppose I have a `HttpHelper` class that has a `GetResponseStream()`, that upload request data showing progress via events `StatusChanged` & `ProgressChanged`.

```
public MemoryStream GetResponseStream() {
    ...
    Status = Statuses.Uploading; // this doesn't raise StatusChanged
    // write to request stream
    ... // as I write to stream, ProgressChanged doesn't get raised too
    Status = Statuses.Downloading; // this too
    // write to response stream
    ... // same here
    Status = Statuses.Idle; // this runs ok. Event triggered, UI updated
}
```

Code **[@pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FeAPB6rU)**. `GetRequestStream()` on line 76. The class itself works fine except the using class need to call it like below

```
HttpHelper helper = new HttpHelper("http://localhost/uploadTest.php");
helper.AddFileHeader("test.txt", "test.txt", "text/plain", File.ReadAllBytes("./test.txt"));
helper.StatusChanged += (s, evt) =>
{
    _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => txtStatus.Text = helper.Status.ToString()));

    if (helper.Status == HttpHelper.Statuses.Idle || helper.Status == HttpHelper.Statuses.Error)
        _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => progBar.IsIndeterminate = false));

    if (helper.Status == HttpHelper.Statuses.Error)
        _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => txtStatus.Text = helper.Error.Message));
};
helper.ProgressChanged += (s, evt) =>
{
    if (helper.Progress.HasValue)
        _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => progBar.Value = (double)helper.Progress));
    else
        _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => progBar.IsIndeterminate = true));
};
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => helper.GetResponseString());
```

If I had called the class using

```
helper.GetResponseString();
```

Then the class itself will work, but events don't seem to be raised. I think it has to do with the UI thread being blocked. How can I at recode the class such that its easier/cleaner for the using class to use it, without all the `_dispatcher` & `Task` stuff.

Also, I will like to know for sure whats causing the events/UI to not update. Even if the code is synchronous, can't it run the property changed/events anyways, its after the read/write afterall?

Comment: You should set the PasteBin syntax highlighting to C#.  http://pastebin.com/FeAPB6rU

Comment: @SLaks, Thanks for notifying me on that, must have been doing PHP yest and forgot to change the language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) instead of hand-crafting this yourself. Use [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) to pass the state of processing to your UI thread.

Comment: While this is probably a good suggestion for this question, I'd like to add a caveat, because there are scenarios in which this might be less good: a problem with this suggestion is that it'll end up consuming a thread for as long as the work is in progress. It's unlikely to be a problem in client-side code (which is what the question seems to be about), but on server-side code it would defeat the point of doing things asynchronously. Full-on async use of networking classes enables far more frugal use of threads, which can sometimes help server scalability. (But would be overengineering here.)